# Firefox gap between inline-block letters in spans

Tags: css

see demo: http://jsbin.com/evesey/41/edit

Each letter is in a `span` element, and the whole sentence is overlapping an input field, to show the difference. this is only caused in Firefox and only when the `spans` are set to `inline-block`. They must be `inline-block`. I tried to play with the `letter-spacing` but it isn't a good solution when the text changes to something else.

Is there a way for this to be fixed? I'm afraid this might just be an unsolvable bug in Firefox rendering inline-blocks...

[image: inline-block gap between letters]

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what the problem is?  While FF and Chrome don't exactly render the letters identically, for me, they look very similar.

Comment: have you tried changing the font-family?

Comment: Upvoted the question : nice case.

Comment: As I said, there is a strange gap between the span elements, but only in Firefox. this is very very strange, as you can see, the text do not align correctly while `inline-block` is applied to the `span` elements.

Comment: Ark - it has nothing to do with the font-family, you could have seen that in the demo page just by playing around. I won't post here stupid questions unless the matter was grave.

Comment: This is strange. Put `margin-left: -0.08px;` inside your `body > div > div span` class. Better than what you currently get at least.

Comment: that won't help since every letter makes different margin that needs to be taken into consideration...some letters makes gap, some don't..

Comment: Make it `display: inline` and if you need to style it play with line-height and padding. Strange FF behavior ... I know you said `inline-block` is a must, so sorry about that. Another possible hint: pseudo selectors, `:after` and `:before`.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference, I looked in ff, chrome and ie9

Comment: I cleaned it up and removed the font-family and it looks fine now. http://jsbin.com/evesey/38/edit or http://jsfiddle.net/X4gws/

Comment: no, i know why this happens....it MUST MUST support ALL fonts, no matter what. and by the way, both your examples looks bad on Firefox...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, after DEEP investigation, I have learned that Firefox applied Kernnig on the input field, but not on the separate letters in the `spans` while Chrome does not apply any kerning at all, thus, rendering a perfect text match. I see this is a Chrome bug then, not kerning by default is not so wise IMHO.

I've managed to remove the forced kerning in a "hacky" way, by adding a zero-width-space character `\u200b` after every character that is printed into the input field.

**Update**: 
seems the kerning is still happening with the above trick, only less "kerned". this is not good.

Comment: it doesn't work, and also the word `kern` isn't even included in the specs on MDN.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-feature-settings